# Unable to connect to Azure Table Storage in windows 2012 r2 and .net core 1.0.1

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I recently upgrade my asp.net core project from the rc2 version to 1.0.1. I am having trouble figuring out how to connect to Azure Table Storage. It seems that something is blocking my connection.

Note that this code is working on my local dev box, **Win10 15063**. It does not work on my dev server, running **Win2012R2**. It was also working with the .net core preview version **1.0.0-preview2-003133**, but not the .net core final version **1.0.1**

I'm using the latest Azure Storage package, 8.1.1

Here's my code

```
var azureTableStorageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=blah_blahstoragedev;AccountKey=Blahblah;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"; //Configuration["AzureStorageConnectionString"];

storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

buildTable = tableClient.GetTableReference(BuildTableName);
buildTable.CreateIfNotExists();
```

It failed with this exception:

Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: 'Unable to connect to the remote server'

- InnerException  {"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8888"}   System.Exception {System.Net.Sockets.SocketException}

> StackTrace    "   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1
>   cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation.Execute(CloudTableClient
>   client, CloudTable table, TableRequestOptions requestOptions,
>   OperationContext operationContext)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable.Exists(Boolean
>   primaryOnly, TableRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext
>   operationContext)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable.CreateIfNotExists(TableRequestOptions
>   requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext)

Comment: Firewall? Is the storage emulator running locally?

Comment: Hey, There might be firewall involved, but there's definitely not a local storage running. However I did specify the conncetion string. They should connect to what my connection string says, right?

Comment: well, its says 127.0.0.1 refused connection, so you did something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested following code on my Windows Server 2012 R2 with .NET Core 1.0.1 installed and it worked fine on my side.

```
public async static void CreateTable(string tableName)
{
    var connectionString = "my connection string";

    var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
    var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

    Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable buildTable = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
    await buildTable.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Create success");
}
```

[image]

The differences of code between yours and mine is that I can’t use CreateIfNotExists method when I build my application. I showed me the following error. So I used CreateIfNotExistsAsync method instead.

*error CS1061: 'CloudTable' does not contain a definition for 'CreateIfNotExists' and no extension method 'CreateIfNotExists' accepting a first argument of type 'CloudTable' could be found*

Please use asynchronous method and tested your code again. Here is a discussion which related to it from GitHub.

*Our NetCore/Netstandard support does not yet include Sync implementation of the APIs.*

[Missing syncronous methods for dotnet core?](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/367)

> the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8888

8888 often use as a port for a proxy or antivirus software. Please mark sure whether the creating table request was blocking by your firewall or antivirus software. I suggest you use a tool(for example, Wireshark) to check whether the network packets has been sent from your server successfully. Following is the request which send from my Windows Server 2012 R2 when I created a new table using .NET Core 1.0.1 and Azure Storage SDK (captured by Fiddler).

```
POST https://mystroagename.table.core.windows.net/Tables() HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json; odata=minimalmetadata
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
Authorization: SharedKey mystroagename:mykey
User-Agent: Azure-Storage/8.1.1 (.NET Core)
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0;NetFx
Prefer: return-no-content
DataServiceVersion: 3.0;
x-ms-client-request-id: 5eeb6570-0ca0-42c7-844a-6acdcc3b7bb9
x-ms-version: 2016-05-31
x-ms-date: Mon, 03 Apr 2017 07:26:43 GMT
Content-Length: 23
Host: mystroagename.table.core.windows.net

{"TableName":"newtablename"}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for trying it out. Let me try it.

Comment: Amor, Thanks for the help. Turns out there's a entry machine.config for defaultproxy that points to 127.0.0.0:8888. Somehow the new .net core respect that and redirect my call to 127.0.0.0:8888